# Ansible dynamic inventory: unable to use group_vars

Tags: ansible

Here is my directory structure,

```
├── README.md
├── internal-api.retry
├── internal-api.yaml
├── ec2.py
├── environments
│   ├── alpha
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── alpha.yaml
│   │   │   ├── internal-api.yaml
│   │   ├── host_vars
│   │   ├── internal_ec2.ini
│   ├── prod
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   |   │   ├── prod.yaml
│   │   │   ├── internal-api.yaml
│   │   │   ├── tag_Name_prod-internal-api-3.yml
│   │   ├── host_vars
│   │   ├── internal_ec2.ini
│   └── stage
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   ├── internal-api.yaml
│       │   ├── stage.yaml
│       ├── host_vars
│   │   ├── internal_ec2.ini
├── roles
│   ├── internal-api
├── roles.yaml
```

I am using separate config for an ec2 instance with tag `Name` = `prod-internal-api-3`,  so I have defined a separate file, `tag_Name_prod-internal-api-3.yaml` in `environments/prod/group_vars/` folder.

Here is my `tag_Name_prod-internal-api-3.yaml`,

```
---
internal_api_gunicorn_worker_type: gevent
```

Here is my main playbook, `internal-api.yaml`

```
- hosts: all
  any_errors_fatal: true
  vars_files:
    - "environments/{{env}}/group_vars/{{env}}.yaml" # this has the ssh key,users config according to environments
    - "environments/{{env}}/group_vars/internal-api.yaml"
  become: yes
  roles:
    - internal-api
```

For `prod` deployemnts, I do `export EC2_INI_PATH=environment/prod/internal_ec2.ini`, likewise for stage and alpha. In `environment/prod/internal_ec2.ini` I have added instance filter, `instance_filters = tag:Name=prod-internal-api-3`

When I run my playbook,

I get this error,

```
fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'internal_api_gunicorn_worker_type' is undefined"}
```

It means that it is not able to pick variable from the file `tag_Name_prod-internal-api-3.yaml`. Why is it happening? Do I need to manually add it in `include_vars`(I don't think that should be the case)?

Comment: It is a tiny bit weird that you are asking why `tag_Name_prod-internal-api-3.yml` isn't auto-discovered for inclusion but at the same time you're **manually** including `environments/{{env}}/group_vars/internal-api.yaml` et al, meaning they certainly are not auto-discovered. I bet if you moved/copied/symlinked `ec2.py` into `environments/prod` and then ran with `EC2_INI_PATH=... ansible-playbook -i environments/prod/ec2.py` it would do what you intend (no manual `vars_files:` required)

Comment: moved ec2.py to `environments/prod` and removed `vars_files`, now no variable has included. Does it automatically picks up all the `environments/prod/group_vars/` files? because its not happening with me. @Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it is really weird, like really really weird. I don't know whether it has been documented or not(please provide link if it is).

If your tag `Name` is like `prod-my-api-1`, then the file name `tag_Name_prod-my-api-1` will not work.

Your filename has to be `tag_Name_prod_my_api_1`. Yeah, thanks ansible for making me cry for 2 days.